# Download attached files in a Zip

Tags: views, files

Im doing a website for photos. The photographer uploads all the images and drupal generates a thumbnail and a resized image.

What i'm trying to do is to put a link , so the final user can download all the original files in a zip files.

Can you guys help me out?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there's a module for that (of course ;) )

[Download module](http://drupal.org/project/download):

> This module can compress any files attached to a node and provides a download link. To use this module you have to extract the PclZip library in /sites/all/libraries/pclzip which can be downloaded here: http://www.phpconcept.net/pclzip/pclzip-downloads.

Comment: How do I use the Download Module?
Please, do you have any instruction about it? Thanks

Comment: @user13680 - the readme needs some work, in the meantime: http://drupal.org/node/1922568#comment-7126430

Answer (score 0):

There's a better suited module available for that functionality now: <s>https://www.drupal.org/project/zipcart, put everything into a cart and download a zip. About to start using zipcart for a project myself</s>

Edit: ended up with [DocBinder](https://www.drupal.org/project/docbinder) because zipcart got abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class.

I'm writing some code at the moment to implement this in Drupal on a node save. I'll add an example later. But for now there are examples on the [ZipArchive](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) page.